# Как мне записать значение id в переменную?

Tags: javascript, jquery

мне нужно взять значение ID и записать в переменную
[image]

```
var params = {
            'IBLOCK_TYPE_ID': 'lists',
            'IBLOCK_ID': '110',
            // 'ELEMENT_CODE': 'element_1'
        };
        BX24.callMethod(
            'lists.element.get',
            params,
            function(result)
            {
                if(result.error())
                    alert("Error: " + result.error());
                else
                    console.log(result.data());
                if (result.more())
                    result.next();
            }
        );
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Обратитесь к этому объекту к его полю `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть предполагаемый массив, внутри которого лежит объект.
Пусть массив называется

```
const users = []
```

Тогда внутри users вы прописываете объект.

Получаете структуру

```
РАЗВЕРНУТЫЙ МАССИВ > 0: {obj:value}
```

Для того, что бы достать нужное значение из поле вы можете пойти несколькими путями, но я предложу один из возможных автоматизированных вариантов.

```
const users = [ 
 { 
   id: '0000001',  
   name: 'Name', 
   stat: 'rest'
 } 
]  

id = users.map(({id}) => id); 
console.log(id);
```

Алгоритм: Перебираете массив, итерируясь по объекту с  data  и в новый массив пушим необходимый результат.

Если автоматизация не важна:

```
 const users = [ 
 { 
   id: '0000001',  
   name: 'Name', 
   stat: 'rest'
 } 
]   

const id = users[0].id;
```

Comment: у меня не получилось, выше добавил пример, я не могу вытащить значение из функции, именно в ней data()

Comment: Могу предположить, что  data, это хоть и функция, но вернула она массив данных. Конечно утверждать не буду, нужно больше информации, но попробуйте  обратится к функции data().ID   или data()[0].ID ,  что-то в том роде. Вообщем обычное обращение к объекту, как показан пример выше.  Разумеется. console.log(result.data().обращение);

Comment: пробовал, не может найти объект

Comment: data is not defined

Comment: Если можно, проверьте тип result.data() Мне интересно это объект или массив или что...

Comment: это объект, по крайней мере когда в алерте выводишь, там получается 5 объектов

Comment: console.log(result.data().NAME) какая ошибка?  (оба варианта name,   NAME)

Comment: undefined во всех

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118367/discussion-between---and-venomphp).

Comment: console.log(result)  проверьте.  Вы вообще точно все пишите в нужной области видимости?

Comment: result is not defined действительно, что-то с видимостью, хотя это очень странно